# How to migrate data with downgrading from Android 7.1.1 to 5.1

Tags: backup, restore, data-transfer

I just bought a new phone and it is running Android 5.1 with little chances for upgrade. On the initial setup, when Android asks were to migrate from, my current phone (with Android 7.1.1) was not available. So I've skipped this step. It, however, has downloaded contacts from, I guess, Google cloud, but the contacts are aged and correspond to my oldest Android I used to have couple years ago. I've tried an app from the play store,  but it has created lots of duplicated records. So I had to reset and start from the beginning.

The questions I have

- How to get my contacts in sync in my particular situation?
- Is it possible to migrate application data?

Comment: A full transfer is unlikely to be done based on the Google backups alone (especially as they don't cover everything). If you're just after your contacts: you can use the contacts app to export/import them (check its menu), but that again might cause dupes with both devices syncing via Google. Are you using the same Google account on both? Did you have contacts sync enabled on the 7.1.1 device?

Comment: I've checked, both phones are using the same account and both indicate almost the same last sync date time. Contact app has 'Share' option, I can use it for exporting new contacts, but how do I find those that were updated?

Comment: 1) strange. If both are syncing via the same account, data should be identical. It's long ago I've used Google for that (I'm syncing with my own DAV). 2) no, not the "share" button. Go via the 3-dot-menu, there's an entry to import/export from/to your SD card. For details, see [my answer here](/a/64221/16575).

Comment: 1) No doubt. If it were not strange I would not ask for help.  My impression that the cloud keeps both old and new versions of contacts and each phone is stuck to what it can understand
2) yes, found export

Comment: Pointer if you want some alternative contacts/calendar solutions: get some account with DAV support (or self-host – SoftwareRecs has some products for that), and use e.g. DAVDroid. Works great for me with a bunch of devices running quite different versions of Android (syncing against my ownCloud). // what other data do you need to migrate? If contacts is all you need, I'd sum up the comments to an answer (after you confirmed it worked out).

Comment: My comment is most likely to be ignored, as it is a suggestion for the future, but here it is. For future migrations, you may want to drop the Google sync and, *if willing to root devices*, make use of apps such as Titanium Backup in order to ensure that most data be available on the new device. *I'm not affiliated with the above app.*

Comment: If you're using Google's sync feature, then your contact should have been taken from [Google Contacts](https://contacts.google.com/). However, "Contacts" app also accepts contacts from other sources, e.g. contacts on Yahoo! account or Hotmail account (check it on your **Android settings - Accounts**), etc. So it might be possible that you have duplicate contacts from Google Contact *and* from other accounts with the same info. In that case, I think you can only merge them *inside* the contact app (not sure about your Contact app's capability since you didn't mention your phone model).